# How do I pull post from standard post format?

Tags: array

I use this code to take a post from the post format.

```
$query = array(
            'showposts' => 5,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video' )
                ),
            ),
        );
```

array( 'post-format-standard' ) is not.

How do I pull from standard format ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: If you just want to display standard posts, use a standard loop: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop

Comment: Thanks but, I have to use it like this in the project.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the entire query before the taxonomy array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `terms` parameter will only accept custom post types and, like you mentioned, `post-format-standard` is not one.

Try instead to use the 'NOT IN' operator to test against the custom posts you don't want to display (all in this case):

```
$query = array(
  'showposts' => 5,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR', // You likely don't need this
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video', 'post-format-image', 'post-format-link', 'post-format-aside', 'post-format-quote', 'post-format-chat', 'post-format-video', 'post-format-chat', 'post-format-audio' ), 
      'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ),
  ),
);
```

The thinking here is that it won't display anything but standard posts.

Reference [Taxonomy_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)